# Sonar Qube Quality Gates plugin in Jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

i've installed and configure a SonanarQube Qualuity Gates plugin and successfully configured it in a non-pipline job. But when u try to configure it in pipline i face an different errors, when i try to make pipline like this:

```
stage ("SonarQube analysis") {
 dir('source') {
            def scannerHome = tool 'sonscanner';
             withSonarQubeEnv('sonar'){
               timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS');
                 withSonarQubeEnv('sonar'){
                      def qg = waitForQualityGate()
             if (qg.status != 'OK') {
              error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
      }
          } 
             } 
                } 
                  }
```

i see this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:283)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:95)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution.start(TimeoutStepExecution.java:46)
```

When as separate step after SonarQube analytics :

```
stage("Quality Gate"){
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
            def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"

          } else {

                echo 'Quality Gate PASSED'

            }

        }

    }
```

Than

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get SonarQube task id and/or server name. Please use the 'withSonarQubeEnv' wrapper to run your analysis.
at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.processStepParameters(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:125)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:107)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:150)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
```

And when pipline :

```
     stage ("SonarQube analysis") {

 dir('source') {

            def scannerHome = tool 'sonscanner';

             withSonarQubeEnv('sonar'){

            sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=android -Dsonar.sources='${WORKSPACE}'/source -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.projectBaseDir='${WORKSPACE}'/source -Dsonar.java.binaries='${WORKSPACE}'/source/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath='${WORKSPACE}'/sourceapp/build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest"

  }    

     }              

       }



  stage("Quality Gate"){

        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout

            def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv

            if (qg.status != 'OK') {error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"

            } else {

                echo 'Quality Gate PASSED'

            }

        }

    }
```

This:

```
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse response from https://sonar//api/ce/task?id=AWCYPE3v1VuUrqmUzLyR:
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to parse response from https://sonar//api/ce/task?id=AWCYPE3v1VuUrqmUzLyR:

Note the double // in the url. You can fix this easily, by removing the trailing slash in the configuration of the plugin on Jenkins.

In Jenkins:

1. Manage Jenkins
2. Configure System
3. Scrol to the section called `SonarQube servers`
4. Remove the trailing `\` from the `Server URL` ;)

It should look something like this:

> `https://sonarcloud.io`

NOT

> `https://sonarcloud.io/`